# set drop-down values based on vlookup

Tags: excel, validation

I have a worksheet `UserEntry` with 2 columns, `Block` and `Address`.  I want to validate both of these based on another worksheet `Validation` with the same column names.  The data on the `Validation` sheet is as follows:

```
Block | Address
---------------
001   | 101
001   | 101.3
001A  | 35
020-1 | 203
020-1 | 203.5
020-1 | 204.1

...
```

There are about 11000 different blocks, and about 40000 block/address pairs.

My goal is that if a user enters a value into the `Block` column on the `UserEntry` sheet, the drop-down choices in the `Address` column change to correspond with that `Block`.

I tried using Custom validation with this formula:

`=VLOOKUP(UserEntry!A2,Validation!A2:B40000)`

But that evaluated to an error.  I saw some solutions in various forums that involved setting named ranges and then having the VLOOKUP() search for the appropriate named range, but it seems like that won't work here because I'd have to create 11000 named ranges.

How can I make the validation drop-down for `Address` include all the values corresponding to a given `Block` value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't mention VBA but here is a solution that uses it.

### Step 1

Create a master table of Block-Address relationships. Make sure this is sorted on `Block`. I used Sheet1:

[image: Master Table]

Cell `E2` is important. You don't actually have to put anything there, but the macro will use it. Cell `E3` is for show only, but you will use the formula (which is commented out here so you can see it)  momentarily.

### Step 2

Create a named range. The formula in `Refers to:` is what you saw in `E3` above, and you can see the reference to cell `E2` here. The formula for your convenience is

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MATCH($E$2,$A:$A,0)-1,1,COUNTIF($A:$A,$E$2),1)
```

[image: Dynamic Range]

### Step 3

Set up a new worksheet (Sheet2) where the data entry will happen. Create data validation for the `Address` column as shown.

[image]

### Step 4

Open the VBA editor and paste this code in the module for `Sheet2`. You can remove the `Debug` statement if you wish. Again note the reference to cell `E2` on `Sheet1`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Debug.Print "fired on " & ActiveCell.Address
  If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
  End If
End Sub
```

### Step 5

Enjoy. Your data validation is now context sensitive. Examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I went with this approach and it works well.  Thank you for the thorough and well-illustrated explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dynamic named range for this.

Assumptions:

1. Validation list is sorted A..Z
2. Validation list is in range `Validation!A:B`
3. Validation list includes headings in row 1
4. On sheet `UserEntry` the `Address` cell to be validated is one cell to the right of the ented `Block`
5. Tried and tested on Excel 2010

Create a *Named Range* to use as validation source (I've used name `ValList`):

```
=OFFSET(Validation!$B$1,MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row"),CELL("col")-1)),Validation!$A:$A,0)-1,0,COUNTIF(Validation!$A:$A,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row"),CELL("col")-1))),1)
```

Add *Data Validation* to the required cells: Allow `List`, Source `=ValList`

1. Uses `INDIRECT`, `ADDRESS` and `CELL` to get a refernce to the user entered *Block* relative to the active cell
2. Uses `MATCH` and `COUNTIF` to get the position and size of the matching *Blocks* in the validation list
3. Uses `OFFSET` to set the return range to the *addreesses* matching the enterd *block*

Comment: I went with @andyholoday's solution instead because it required fewer assumptions, and was therefore flexible enough to meet my existing needs.

Comment: If you look closely you will find it uses the same assumptions.  The key difference is his uses VBA to access the active cell, mine uses the `CELL` function, IMHO a much cleaner solution.  If the stated assumptions don't fit your sheet layout, post back and I can adapt it to suit.

Comment: +1 to @chrisneilsen for VBA avoidance. I did not know how to wrangle `CELL` to do this. Nice job!

Comment: chris, I've been trying to figure out how to implement your solution; i needed to change `cell("col")-1` to `cell("col")-2` so it would fit my layout.  But the validation results in an error if the `Block` column on `UserEntry` is blank, even if I enable "Ignore Blanks" on the validation.  Working on this now--do you have any advice?

Comment: @sigil I assume you want to change thne column offset to -2 because user entered block is 2 cells to the left of the cell to be validated?  I've tried this edit and it works for me.  I _do_ get warnings that _"The Source currently evaluates to an error"_ when moving around the validation dialog.  This in itself is not a problem, its just telling you some cells don't currently meet the validation criteria.  The ignore blanks option relates to values entered on the sheet - with it turned off you would not be able to blank a cell if blank does not meet the criteria (which it doesn't in this case)

Comment: @chrisneilsen, it's not a big problem if I enter the validation manually, but when I try to do it through VBA using `Range.Validation.Add` then it fails with `error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error`.  I haven't figured out how to override the error and make it apply the validation anyways; i suppose that's a separate problem.

Comment: @sigil ahh, new information - vba! I'll have a look into it.  As you said this would best be asked as a new question, that way others are more likely to see it too.

Comment: @sigil I've found a _work around_ to your vba error problem.  1) Modify the `ValList` named range to refer to a simple range. 2) set the validation. 3) restore 'ValList` to the original reference.  A bit clunky, but it seems to work.

Comment: This was super helpful, is it possible to modify the formula to return a unique set of values for the dropdown (my column that is returned has duplicates in it)

Comment: @j  you could write a vba function to return a unique list, and use that as the validation source, via a named range