# trying to set dependent list validation w/ VBA, getting "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I'm trying to set list validation for a cell based on the contents of another cell, using a named range that matches the contents of a cell on my data entry sheet to a range on the `Validation` sheet (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657811/set-drop-down-values-based-on-vlookup)).  The named range's formula is:

```
=OFFSET(validation!$B$1,MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row"),CELL("col")-2)),validation!$A:$A,0)-1,0,COUNTIF(validation!$A:$A,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row"),CELL("col")-2))),1)
```

The problem is that if the cell referred to by `ADDRESS(CELL("row"),CELL("col")-2)` is empty, setting the validation with VBA using `Range.Validation.Add` gives an error:

```
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

and then it doesn't add the validation to the cell.  Is there any kind of error handling I can do on the `Validation.Add` call to make sure the validation gets set?  Or a way to modify the named range formula so that it outputs a value even if the contents of `ADDRESS(CELL("row"),CELL("col")-2)` don't return a match on the `validation` sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a *work around* try this:

1. Modify the `ValList` named range to refer to a simple range.
2. Set the validation.
3. Restore 'ValList` to the original reference.

A bit clunky, but it seems to work.

```
Sub SetVal()
    Dim s As String

    s = ActiveWorkbook.Names("ValList").RefersTo
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("ValList").RefersTo = "=UserEntry!$A$3:$A$6"

    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=ValList"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Names("ValList").RefersTo = s
End Sub
```

Comment: It does indeed seem to work.  Thanks for all your help on this problem!