# Set distinct drop-down values based on vlookup

Tags: excel

```
Col A  Col B
Fruit  Grapes
Fruit  Mango 
Fruit  Mango
Veg    Carrot
Veg    Brinjal
Fruit  Banana
Veg    Carrot
```

I have a similar requirement as shown in this thread
[set drop-down values based on vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657811/set-drop-down-values-based-on-vlookup)

This works fine, however now the requirement for me is in Column B there will be duplicates and the dropdown has to show only distinct values. Can any one help me with this

See file here [Requirement](http://sdrv.ms/GQiehQ)

**I want to achieve this by pure Excel formulas and not by VBA code.**

Comment: Actually, are you looking for the drop-down to change according to the cell you are in? My example doesn't do that currently.

Comment: Yes, i wanted a dropdown values listing out the respective values. For example Fruit should list out Grapes, Mango, Banana

Comment: So when, and how, should this all happen? In a separate column?

Comment: Similar to the example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657811/set-drop-down-values-based-on-vlookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1** - This just shows how to create a unique list in a drop-down.

Here's a screenshot, but currently it requires that there is a row above the data(?). This provides a unique list of items in a Data Validation drop-down. (All the formulas below can be made easier to create by naming some ranges beforehand.)

[image]

The array formula in E2 is shown in the comment. Use `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` to enter an array formula, then drag this down as far as necessary - the #N/As will begin to appear at the bottom.

Gosh, it's hard to describe :). The COUNTIF essentially generates a sequence of 1s and 0s to indicate whereabouts in column B the *previous* (above) values in column E are positioned in column B. This sequence always starts with a 0 (for the formula in E2) because it's looking for a blank which doesn't occur in column B - so this will grab the first item, Grapes.

The MATCH then finds the first 0 in this sequence of 0s and 1s, which indicates that a value (in column B) hasn't already appeared in column E.

INDEX then uses this MATCHed value to retrieve the *new* unique item from column B.

Then a **Defined Name** is created (on the Formulas tab) that gets all the values in column E, but only down to the first occurrence of '#', which indicates there are no more unique values in the list.

This Defined Name is then used in the Data Validation.

**Part 2** - The Answer (with VBA)

The following VBA code is required so that clicking in a cell in C11:C18 will change the value in F1, which generates the unique list underneath, which populates the data-validation list in C11:C18.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C11:C18")) Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

It requires the formulas and defined-name as shown in the following screenshot. The formula in F2 is different to F3, which is then copied down.

The number 10 in the formula in F3 is just a large number (of rows).

[image]

- Column E are the unique items.
- Column D are the corresponding categories.
- Column F are the unique items for the category in cell F1 (extracted form column E).

**Part 3** - Without VBA

Use the formula `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row"),CELL("col")-1))` in cell F1. When you click into a cell in C11:C18 you need to press **F9** to recalculate the worksheet, which updates the drop-down list.

Recalculating is necessary to update the `CELL("row")` and `CELL("col")` values.

**Part 4** - Without pressing F9

It can be achieved without having to press F9, but it means spreading all the categories across different columns (G1 and to the right in the below screenshot). This can also be achieved with the array formula `=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$A$2:$A$8),0))` in G1.

The #N/As can also be removed the the drop-down lists with strategic use of IFERROR() in the formulas from G2 onwards, substituting "". Alternatively, using:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$G$1,1,MATCH(Sheet1!B11,Sheet1!$G$1:$J$1,0)-1,MATCH("#",OFFSET(Sheet1!$G$1,1,MATCH(Sheet1!B11,Sheet1!$G$1:$J$1,0)-1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$G:$G)-1,1),-1),1)
```

as the defined-name `Items` would not only remove the #N/As but also the redundant ("") values that IFERROR() would leave in the drop-down lists. (The cursor needs to be positioned in C11 when creating this defined-name.)

[image]

Apologies for the length of this, but hope it is of interest to someone.

Comment: Andy, Thanks for giving the solution. But i want to achieve this by pure excel formulas and not using any VBA code. I should have made it clear when posting this question but it did not, sorry. Also the requirement is as per the attached Excel sheet

Comment: You should have said - this is a programming forum. Use superuser.com for non-programming questions. Anyway, I've added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Andy! I liked your Part 4 but spreading across the categories in columns will be difficult as the categories would be dynamic and can be added to master anytime also we have more than 100 categories

Comment: Excel 2007+ has 16k+ columns and once the formulas have been entered they can just be copied down, and across, to extract more unique items and categories. But I appreciate that it may be a little off-putting to maintain these.

Comment: I tried with the Part 4 approach but for some reasons it is not working out. Can you please implement in the attached workbook and send it. Thanks in advance