# Data validation based on LOOKUP

Tags: excel

I've got two tables. Table A and Table B.

Table A has the following three columns: "Attribut ID", "Attribut Name" and "Value".
Example rows from table A(comma representing a new column):

- "10000, Length, 3M"
- "10000, Length, 5M"
- "10000, Length, 7M"
- "20000, Depth, 1,5M"
- "20000, Depth, 3M"
- "20000, Depth, 4,5M"

Table B has the following three columns: "Product Number", "Attribut ID" and "Value"
Example rows from table B(comma representing a new column):

- "38-500351, 10000, 3M"

The sheet will be used by clients to input data, so I want to make everything as simple and as validated as possible, to minimize errors. Currently clients put in the "Value" in Table B (3M in the example) manually.

My goal is to change this to be based on a dropdown list, or at least be validated, based on Table A. So if 10000 is put in as the "Attribut ID" in table B, only "3M", "5M" and "7M" can be put in as values.

I've found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657811/set-drop-down-values-based-on-vlookup), which seems very similar, but I've been unable to figure out how to use it. Any help would be much appreciated. Avoiding VBA would be preferred if possible.

I've succesfully adapted Axcel's answer. Here's the modified code to adapt it to my sheet:

```
=INDEX('Attribut værdier'!$C:$C;MATCH(INDIRECT("RC[-2]";FALSE);'Attribut værdier'!$A:$A;0)):INDEX('Attribut værdier'!$C:$C;MATCH(INDIRECT("RC[-2]";FALSE);'Attribut værdier'!$A:$A;1))
```

I've changed "," to ";" and the sheet references. Other than that I've made no changes and everything works.

Comment: Is the Table A sorted ascending by "Attribut ID" per default?

Comment: Currently none of the tables are sorted. The user will be inputting more data on often, but sorting the data by Attribute ID would be just fine if that made it easier.

Comment: I've edited the code based on Axel's comments and everything is wokring now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have a situation like this:
[image]

Note that the Attribut ID in column A is sorted ascending.

Create a Name named "ValueList" using the Name Manager which refers to

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH(INDIRECT("RC[-1]",FALSE),Sheet1!$A:$A,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH(INDIRECT("RC[-1]",FALSE),Sheet1!$A:$A,1))
```

How to use Name manager, see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bmmanage_names_by_using_the_name_manage

The "RC[-1]" within the INDIRECT must be changed accordingly the language version of your Excel. For German Excel it has to be "ZS(-1)".

This named range will dynamically get the range in column C from the first occurance of the "Attribut ID" till the last occurance of this "Attribut ID" in column A. The "Attribut ID" is taken from the cell left of the cell it is assigned to.

Then you can use this named range as source for the list within Data Validation (Source =ValueList) for the dropdowns in column G.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Axel. I've edited my post to reflect your solution, but still getting some errors though. Please see the end of my post.

Comment: You can't put the formula directly as source to the data validation. You have to create a name "ValueList" which refers to the formula and then use this as source.

Comment: Sorry if I didnt make that clear. I have created a ValueList name which is referred to by the Data Validation

Comment: It's working now. I'll update my original post with what I did and select your answer as correct. Thanks a lot for your help, Axel! :-)