# Unique Values from Dynamic List in Excel

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I'm using this answer, and I didn't know if I should comment or make my own question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660722/1640313

But, I'd like to modify this answer to now have the dynamic range "ValList" used in the dropdown to only show me unique values. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to edit your question to show which of the answers you are using and you need to show what you have attempted.

Comment: The link I provided links to the exact answer I'm using from the question, not to the general question.

Comment: So what have you attempted to solve your problem?

Comment: Is it not enough to say that I barely understand the formula I've used enough to know how to modify it much? I've researched how to find unique values, but those methods rely on array-based formulas and filling a column with those unique values. I'm far out of my depth with this excel formula and method, so, I'm looking for some assistance. *shrug*