# VBA drop down list

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I have `Sheet1` as data

```
Column J 
Name of header AccNo
```

On `Sheet2` i make drop down list

```
891-0001 PARKING EXPENSES
891-0002 AIRFARE EXPENSES
```

I want to show drop down list on `Sheet1` from that `Sheet2` but show result `891-0001` only. Please help with the Macro code.

Comment: Is the desired output always the first 8 characters?

Comment: sorry how to make the dropdown list with the left function?

Comment: If i choose from drop down list, i want show that 8 characters only

Comment: If your drop down is in cell `A1`, you can type the following into `B2` to see how the formula works. `B2 = Left(A1, 8)`

Comment: I want the result on same cell

Comment: So you want your data validation drop down to only show the first 8 characters of your string? Can you show how your excel is set up with some sample data plz. It seems that there may be a language barrier stopping you from going into detail. This is when photos become extremely useful :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set drop-down values based on vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657811/set-drop-down-values-based-on-vlookup)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$J$1" Then     'Cell J1 is the dropdown list
    On Error GoTo errorhandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Selection.Validation.Delete
    Target.Value = Left(Target.Value, 8)
    Selection.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=List"   'Define selection as List name
 End If

ErrorExit:
Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub
errorhandler:
Resume ErrorExit

End Sub
```